# Return value of hidden field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a kind of e-commerce site with [jCart](http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/) as a school project. I would like to do the following:

I would like to get the value of a hidden field and return it at another location on the same page.

While browsing Stack Overflow I found this code to get the value of the hidden:

```
<script> var subt = $('#jcart-subtotal').val();</script>
```

This works as expected. I checked it by using `alert(subt)`.

I tried `return(subt);` instead of alert, because I want the value to be printed on the page itself, not shown in an alert message.

How should I do to print the value instead of have it shown in an alert popup?

Comment: $('body').append(subt);

Comment: `$('#some_other_element').html(subt)`

Comment: Please complete some basic tutorials before asking here. We will not teach you the basics here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this wherever you want to show the value on page:

```
<span id='showMe'></span>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('#showMe').html($('#jcart-subtotal').val());
```

Comment: Thank you verry much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the returned value to any elements like

```
var subt = $('#jcart-subtotal').val();
```

Add one element in html file like this

```
<span id="grandTotal"></span> //or <label id="grandTotal"></label>
```

and finally,

```
$("#grandTotal").html(subt);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want your output to be put in.

Supposing you have a page structure with some DOM elements here and there, you just need to access the target DOM element you want and use its `html()` setter to do the job.

```
$("#myTargetSpan").html($('#jcart-subtotal').val());
```

Would put the value of your input into an element which has "myTargetSpan" id.

The `return` instruction is used when your code is called as a function, to return the value to the caller for further use.